# Adding a new row erases my already added products on the invoice form in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I created invoice form. In order to add products, I have created a table with `Add new row` button to add products. Now when I am clicking it, it erases already added products.

My requirement is that when I click on `Add new Row`, my already added products in the table should not get erased.

Below is the image of my `invoice.html form`

[image]

`invoice.html` code of the table to add products

```
    <!--
  Generated template for the InvoicePage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
   <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>invoice</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <form #invoiceForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(invoiceForm.value)">
      <div>
            <input type="text" name="filterText" [(ngModel)]="filterText" style="float:left" (keypress)="isShow=true" (click)="isShow=true"/> 
        </div>      
      <div style="border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;width:35px;height: 23px;float: left;text-align:center;border-left: 0px;padding: 4px;" (click)="isShow = !isShow">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-dropdown" md="md-arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div><a style="margin-left:15px;text-decoration:none" (click)="addNewCust()">Add New Customer</a></div>
      <div style="clear:both;float:left;border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;width:198px;height:88px;overflow:auto;border-top:0px;cursor:pointer" *ngIf="isShow">      
          <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let list of custList | filter:filterText" style="list-style:none" (click)="assignValue(list)">{{list.partyname}}</li>
            </ul>       
        </div>  
      <div style="clear:both;margin-top:120px">
            <label>Billing Address</label>
            <textarea name="address" [(ngModel)]="address"></textarea>
            <label>Terms</label>
            <select name="terms" ngModel>
                    <option>NET 15</option>
                    <option>NET 30</option>
             </select>
            <label>Invoice Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="invoiceDate" value="{{invoiceDate | date:d}}"/>
            <label>Due date</label>
            <input type="text" name="dueDate" value="{{dueDate | date:d}}"/>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both">
            <label>Place of Supply</label>
            <select name="pos" ngModel>
                <option>Delhi</option>
                <option>Mumbai</option>
                <option>Bengaluru</option>  
            </select>
        </div>
    <div style="margin-top:15px">
       <table>
              <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Product/Service</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Tax</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let items of inVoiceItems;let i=index;">
                    <td>{{i+1}}</td> 
                    <td style="width:198px">
                        <input type="text" name="prdText" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems[i].prdText" style="width:198px;border:0px"/>
                        <!--<div style="clear:both;border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;width:198px;height:88px;overflow:auto;cursor:pointer" *ngIf="isShowPrd">       
                                <ul>
                                    <li *ngFor="let list of prdList" style="list-style:none" (click)="assignPrdValue(list,i)">{{list.PRODUCTSERVICE}}</li>
                                </ul>       
                        </div>-->
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="prdDesc" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems[i].prdDesc" style="width:198px;border:0px"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="prdQty" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems[i].prdQty" style="width:198px;border:0px"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="prdRate" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems[i].prdRate" style="width:198px;border:0px"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="prdAmt" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems[i].prdAmt" style="width:198px;border:0px"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="prdTax" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems[i].prdTax" style="width:198px;border:0px"/></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><ion-icon ios="ios-trash" md="md-trash" (click)="deleteRow(i)"></ion-icon></td>
                </tr>
        </table>     
        <input type="button" value="Add New Row" (click)="addRow()" style="margin-top:5px"/>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

`invoice.ts` code

```
  addRow(){
    this.inVoiceItems.push({'prdText':'','prdDesc':'','prdQty':'','prdRate':'','prdAmt':'','prdTax':''});
  }
```

[**StackBlitz repo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rvjjym)

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Can you try with the submit button removed?

Comment: i have updated my html code, this is inside `<form>` tag, can that be of any issue ? secondly i commented the submit button, still the same issue, let me try stackblitz.com, i never tried that

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Hey @user2828442 Did my answer help you, or is there some trouble still? :)

Comment: Hi user2828442. Would you reply to @AJT_82 please? I see that you are still signing in and accepting assistance here.

Answer (score 1):

This is because we are dealing with a form. In template driven forms, the `name` attribute needs to be unique, so that the fields will not be evaluated as one and the same. So what is happening now, is that when you push an empty object, all fields get the empty object values, therefore you loose your data in the DOM. If you'd inspect your array, it actually has the correct values, this just affects the form values.

So solve this by giving the fields unique names, which can be achieved by adding the index, so for example in your iteration do this:

```
<input name="prdDesc{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="inVoiceItems[i].prdDesc" />
```

where we just add the index `{{i}}` in the name.

Here's your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4hy4oi?file=pages/home/home.html)**